# Alignment of minipages and colorbox

Tags: color, minipage, colorbox

I have this document which I try to reproduce in Latex. I am using the `colorbox` and `minipage`. But I got confused with an alignment. Can I get the expected results with current packages or should I try something else? Tanks in advanced.

**Expected results**:
[image]

**Actual results**:
[image]

**Actual code**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Last name, first name, patronymic name} \\

\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hspace{-30mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}{\centering
\textbf{Ivanova Nadezda Ivanovna } \\
}\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}

Date of birth \\
\begin{minipage}[t]{-1mm}
\hspace{-30mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}{\centering
\textbf{January 01, 1985} \\
}\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Also the grey color looks different than on original document, but I think I will get how to changed it by my own in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well use a `\parbox` in this case:

[image]

### Note:

- The `showframe` package was used to show the borders. Remove it in your actual use case.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{calc,showframe} 

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Last name, first name, patronymic name} \\
\colorbox{gray}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering\textbf{Ivanova Nadezda Ivanovna}}}

\noindent
Date of birth~%
\colorbox{gray}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{Date of birth~}-\fboxsep}{\centering January 01, 1985}}%
\par\medskip
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter Grill, thank you very much! It works perfect for me :)